# Is there any way to display image in client browser without uploading it to server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing a  simple "Book" create page in ASP.NET MVC. User can create book by filling title,year etc.. and selecting a cover image. When user press "Create" button Form sends image and data to Controller action called "Create" then I save image to disk and data to database.

But I want to display image when user select image by file dialog.To do this As far as I know I must upload image to server then display in client browser.But if a user cancels the "Create" operation after uploading image, the image will remain in the server's disk.So How can I deal with these temp images or Is there any way to display image in client browser without upload to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security reasons, you will not be able to display the images to the users without uploading them to the server. Displaying images from file system is considered a security risk.

EDIT: To remove the unused images, you can create a thread to run a cleanup routine to which will delete them from the upload directory regularly.

Comment: Running a backgroud thread to cleanup seems most suitable way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Silverlight, for example:

In Page.xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Select image file">
    <Image x:Name="img1">
</StackPanel>
```

and in Page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Page : UserControl
{
    public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);
    }

    void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn1_Click);
    }

    void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Stream s = ofd.File.OpenRead();
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(s);
            img1.Source = bi;
            s.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.insidercoding.com/post/2008/08/17/Reading-Local-Files-in-Silverlight.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can using javascript

Javascript:

```
function showThumbnail(files){
  for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    var file = files[i]
    var imageType = /image.*/
    if(!file.type.match(imageType)){
      console.log("Not an Image");
      continue;
    }

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
    image.file = file;
    thumbnail.appendChild(image)

    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (function(aImg){
      return function(e){
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
      };
    }(image))
    var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    image.onload= function(){
      ctx.drawImage(image,100,100)
    }
  }
}

var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image");
fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
  var files = this.files
  showThumbnail(files)
},false)
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="upload-image" multiple="multiple"></input>
<div id="thumbnail"></div>
```

You just need the input field and The div to display the thumbnail image, and on change for the input field will call showThumbnail function which will append img inside the "thumbnail" div.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with Simple javascript...

assign the selected image path.. to image tag prefixing the **file://**, n it works the way you want it to be

Comment: Its a security risk, most browsers will not display the images from local file system.

Comment: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Linking+to+local+file+under+Firefox
This works fine under Internet Explorer, but Firefox and Mozilla block links to local files for security purposes. If you are happy with the risk of linking to local content, you can override the security policy and also enable linking in Firefox