# Is that possible to display image thumbnail without uploading it to the server?

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload, uploadify

I want let user to upload images to server add some info (like description, tags) about each image.
I use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to upload multiple images.

I wonder if it is possible to show thumbnails of the images (while the user enters the additional info about each image) **before** the images are actually uploaded to the server.

I want user to have the following experience:

- Select multiple image files
- **Immediately after that** enter additional information about each image **while seeing images thumbnails**
- Press `Upload Files` button to upload images to server, and go to drink coffee...

I found [this script](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/), but I think it also uploads the file **before** displaying the image thumbnail.

I would appreciate any help !

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771581/is-there-any-way-to-display-image-in-client-browser-without-uploading-it-to-serve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you could enforce an HTML 5 capable browser you could use the file-api

Example: http://html5demos.com/file-api

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is possible. Use the `FileReader` object to get a data URL (or use `File.url` if you are sure the Client implements it.) and assign it to an `new Image()`object. Then you can  insert the image into DOM.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the standard-based HTML5 APIs, you can use a plugin such as Flash or [Browserplus](http://browserplus.yahoo.com/).

There is actually a ready-made application which might do exactly what you want. It's called [**Plupload**](http://plupload.com/). You can upload your files / images using a variety of "runtimes", and do client-side image resizing before uploading. I guess you can hook a thumbnail preview somewhere in there, in certain runtimes.

Otherwise, you can try building what you want from scratch, using the HTML5 / Gears / [BrowserPlus](http://browserplus.org/docs/) / etc. APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure flash and java can both do it. Flash would require certain (obvious) security precautions (ie, you can do this for any file, it must be selected by the user).
Meanwhile java would show a security popup.

Answer (score 0):

[Xavier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4336887/xavier) posted this solution on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368910/html-display-image-after-selecting-filename), and I tried to improove it to work with multiple file inputs. I hope it helps.

```
$("body").on('change', 'input:file', function(e){
for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
             img.src = reader.result;
        }
        img.width = "50";
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        if($(this).next().hasClass('image_place')){
          $(this).next('.image_place').html('').append(img);
        }else {
          $(this).after('<div class="image_place"></div>');
          $(this).next('.image_place').append(img);
        }
    }
});
```

It scans all file inputs in the document body and reads the image using the FileReader api. If it finds any images, it creates a div called "image_place" where he puts the image. If there's already a image inside, the script replaces the image.